# Need Swift Mailer to send emails as UTF-8

Tags: emails, plugin-freeform

I have a Craft 3 site that used Freeform Pro for a contact form. All submissions from this form need to be sent, via email to a third party vendor who parses the information and submits it to a CRM. The format for the emails they receive is very specific: plain-text, utf-8 character set.

When I send a test email from the contact form, it appears to default to ascii if there isn't a utf-8 character in the message. Is there a way to have SwiftMailer to send all emails as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but try setting this in your public `index.php` file right before Craft executes:

```
\Swift_Preferences::getInstance()->setCharset('UTF-8');
```

Based on https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#setting-the-character-set

Comment: Is the \ a typo? Looking at the Swift Mailer docs it doesn't seem to be included

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Thank you for the Swift Mailer references though.